# iOS 7 UITabBar badge position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios7, uitabbar

Is there any way to adjust the position of the UITabBar badge in iOS 7? The badge now blocks the tab bar icon a bit more than I would like.

iOS 6:
[image]

iOS 7:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, can you provide the method by which you are setting the tab bar image?

I had the same problem that you did, and fixed it by using `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`:

```
UIImage *image = // Your tab bar item image
UIImage *selected = // Your selected tab bar item image

image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
selected = [selected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

controller.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                      image:image
                                              selectedImage:selected];
```

Cheers!

Comment: This only fixed the unselected image.  The selected image for me still looks like shadowing is applying.  Any help?

Comment: @Halsafar, You need to set your tab item selected image as well. iOS 7 badge will overlay you image if you don't set the selected image and unselected image. add [tabBarItem setSelectedImage: selectedImage]; to your tabBar controller viewDidLoad method should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the badge is placed in a certain position relative to the image. So if you have no image, the badge is in the upper left corner of the tabBarItem.

So - to position the badge, adjust the border of blank pixels around the .png you're using for the tabBarItem image.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not possible to adjust appearance of the badge.**

If you really want to have it different, I think implementing custom overlay on `UITabBar` should be pretty easy. That way you could put there any custom text, not just numbers.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 SDK depreciate 3 key method we used to customize tabbar

```
- (void)setFinishedSelectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:(UIImage *)unselectedImage

- (UIImage *)finishedUnselectedImage

- (UIImage *)finishedSelectedImage
```

They suggest their alternatives in docs as @Daniel Amitay suggests.

Documentation is here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage: