# How to adjust Tab bar badge position when using custom tab bar image and inset without tab bar title?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, badge

[image: Badge]

I'm not able to reposition badge to the default position as it normally should be. I've tried this solution and few more but none work.
[How to adjust tab bar badge position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236823/how-to-adjust-tab-bar-badge-position)

My issue may be with Tab bar images rather than badge position. I've played a lot with tab bar image sizes, insets etc but none seem to work.

Does anyone know how to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func repositionBadge(tab: Int){

   for badgeView in self.tabBarController!.tabBar.subviews[tab].subviews {

       if NSStringFromClass(badgeView.classForCoder) == "_UIBadgeView" {
          badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
          badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-17.0,   1.0, 1.0)
        }
    }

}
```

Please note the tab integer is NOT zero-indexed, so the first tab will be number 1, the 2nd number 2, etc.