# How to change UITabBarItem Badge position?

Tags: ios, count, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, badge

This is how my Tabbar is looking right now.

[image]

How do I move that badge so that it overlaps the top right of the bell icon? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236823/how-to-adjust-tab-bar-badge-position

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 7 UITabBar badge position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165671/ios-7-uitabbar-badge-position)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
func repositionBadge(tabIndex: Int){

    for badgeView in self.tabBarController!.tabBar.subviews[tabIndex].subviews {

        if NSStringFromClass(badgeView.classForCoder) == "_UIBadgeView" {
            badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-17.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

pay attention, tabIndex starts from 1

Comment: Beware: this uses private API, Apple might reject your app for using this.

Comment: It doesn't work properly.
Badge layer reset after tab selection.

Comment: Perfect answer bro

Comment: Hi @Marcos can you update the answer for the latest OS version as this won't work in iOS 14+

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple example with a red spot [githubGist](https://gist.github.com/MrBoog/bd9883483671218fc37002178985df3a). 
And of course, you can custom the your own `badgeView = UIView()` if you wanna add a label inside.

**Swift 4.2**

```
fileprivate let tabBarItemTag: Int = 10090
extension UITabBar {
    public func addItemBadge(atIndex index: Int) {
        guard let itemCount = self.items?.count, itemCount > 0 else {
            return
        }
        guard index < itemCount else {
            return
        }
        removeItemBadge(atIndex: index)

        let badgeView = UIView()
        badgeView.tag = tabBarItemTag + Int(index)
        badgeView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        badgeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let tabFrame = self.frame
        let percentX = (CGFloat(index) + 0.56) / CGFloat(itemCount)
        let x = (percentX * tabFrame.size.width).rounded(.up)
        let y = (CGFloat(0.1) * tabFrame.size.height).rounded(.up)
        badgeView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 10, height: 10)
        addSubview(badgeView)
    }

    //return true if removed success.
    @discardableResult
    public func removeItemBadge(atIndex index: Int) -> Bool {
        for subView in self.subviews {
            if subView.tag == (tabBarItemTag + index) {
                subView.removeFromSuperview()
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When using iOS 13 or newer, the badge position can be changed by assigning an `UITabBarItemAppearance` object to the item appearance properties of an `UITabBarAppearance` object, and assign this to the **appearance** property of your **tabBar** control.

Example:

```
 let itemAppearance = UITabBarItemAppearance()
 itemAppearance.normal.badgePositionAdjustment.horizontal = 10
    
 let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
 appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance = itemAppearance
 appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance = itemAppearance
 appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance = itemAppearance

 tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Marco Santarossa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38973225/1423345), I updated it by making it into a `UITabBarController` extension, with a few additional tweaks:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    func repositionBadgeLayer(_ badgeView: UIView) {
        if NSStringFromClass(badgeView.classForCoder) == "_UIBadgeView" {
            badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-17.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        }
    }

    func repositionBadges(tab: Int? = nil) {
        if let tabIndex = tab {
            for badgeView in self.tabBar.subviews[tabIndex].subviews {
                repositionBadgeLayer(badgeView)
            }
        } else {
            for tabBarSubviews in self.tabBar.subviews {
                for badgeView in tabBarSubviews.subviews {
                    repositionBadgeLayer(badgeView)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it on your custom `UITabBarController` class, simply call:

1. `repositionBadges()` to apply on every tab bar item available in the tab bar

   **or**
2. `repositionBadges(0)` with `0` referring to the tab bar item index, for selective application

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure transforming the badge layer can be solition since it has some defects:

- it is reset after tab selection
- it keeps transfroming once badge lable changes

I came up with another solution

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        self.standatartTabBarAppearance.inlineLayoutAppearance.normal.badgePositionAdjustment.horizontal = .init(16.0)
        self.standatartTabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.badgePositionAdjustment.horizontal = .init(16.0)
        self.standatartTabBarAppearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance.normal.badgePositionAdjustment.horizontal = .init(16.0)
    }
self.tabBar.standardAppearance = self.standatartTabBarAppearance
```