# Adjust UITabBarItem Badge position?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem, badge

I change badge position with this code:

```
for tabBarButton in self.tabBar.subviews{
            for badgeView in tabBarButton.subviews{
                let className=NSStringFromClass(badgeView.classForCoder)
                if  className == "_UIBadgeView"
                {
                    badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
                    badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-5.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                }
            }
        }
```

As I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973053/how-to-change-uitabbaritem-badge-position)

I need change it frequently. As a result, the badge jumps:

[image: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3og0ILQSxcXE8QucFi]

Comment: can you try badgeView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 10, width: badgeView.frame.size.width, height: badgeView.frame.size.height) instead of transform ?

Comment: @nikdange_me thanks, it sets badge frame. but after I select other tab, badge get initial frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started do this cycle every time, when I change a badge value. 
All is fine now, except little visible shift on start.

Comment: how this answer solve your problem ? explain a little more.

Comment: @pawan badge is staying on specific place, not jumping everytime